# override ActiveRecord setter for "null" string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, form-data

I am using javascript FormData in many places in my app, but unfortunately nil (js) values are encoded as "null" string.

It would be easy to fix this in each individual case by replacing "null" with null in an ActiveRecord before_save callback.

But is there a place within ActiveRecord itself that would do this for my whole app? I'd like to override an ActiveRecord method to include the substitution of "null" with null. Any suggestions where in ActiveRecord this could be done?

Comment: Are you sure that FormData is converting `null` to `"null"`? Can you show us how you're using FormData? Trying to convert `"null"` to `nil` at the model level is not the right way to solve this, this is a problem that's occurring at the edges of your application and that's where it should be solved.

Comment: thank you for your interest @muistooshort. In fact, strangely, it's in the FormData spec that nil should be encoded as "null". I didn't find the actual spec because there's a bug report on chromium.org that indicates that the behaviour I'm seeing is what's required. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331180. If I can solve it in just one place, that's my preference, vs many "edge" places. FormData is opaque to modification I think.

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly stupid behavior on FormData's part, whoever is responsible for that should never be allowed near a keyboard again. I'd wrap `FormData` in JavaScript and have `append` ignore anything with a `null` or `undefined` value. Failing that, process `params` in your controllers to clean up the the `"null"` stupidity and hope that none of your strings are ever supposed to be `"null"`. I adjusted the tags to maybe attract someone that knows how to deal with FormData's broken nonsense.

Comment: Yes @muistooshort, it's totally weird behaviour. And yes, fixing FormData is the "right" place. But my javascript chops suck and Ruby is fun and easy. So suppose you were going to fix it in ActiveRecord... where would that be? I'm willing to accept that anyone with first name or last name of "null" or who lives in a place called "null" will have problems with my app!

Comment: Sorry but I wouldn't do at the model level, that's the wrong thing to do and we're supposed to be professionals here :) I'd bite the bullet, learn more JavaScript, and wrap `FormData` or monkey patch `append` with something sensible. Sorry, I can't in good conscience tell you how to do the wrong thing.

Comment: @muistooshort (and any others) the problem is that monkey patching FormData's append method won't work... it's the output of FormData that is the problem that needs fixing, and that's being handled inside jQuery ajax, which accepts FormData directly. So it's really ugly in js.

Comment: No it isn't, just replace `FormData`'s `append` with a function that does nothing if the value is `null` or `undefined` and punts to the original `append` otherwise.

Comment: @muistooshort, you're right. Your idea eliminates the "null" string being sent. But it still requires an accommodation at the receiving end, which you were opposed to. It does not have the same outcome for the model if the parameter is missing compared to if it has a value of null. If it's missing, ActiveRecord leaves the value unchanged AFAICT. I need "null" to be interpreted as null.